# How to fix overlapping text in scrjura TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, scrjura

In scrjura, when a 2-digit clause has a subclause, text in the table of contents overlaps. Here is the example when it happens with § 11a:

[image]

How do I fix this?

```
\documentclass{scrreport}
\usepackage[juratotoc]{scrjura}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{contract}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\SubClause{title={Subclause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\end{contract}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth]{tocline}{cpar}
```

to adjust the space for the (sub)clause numbers in ToC automatically.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreport}
\usepackage[juratotoc]{scrjura}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth]{tocline}{cpar}% <t added

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{contract}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\Clause{title={Clause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\SubClause{title={Subclause}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
\end{contract}
\end{document}
```

[image]